# How can I fix the broken "new item" link after deleting the InfoPath Form for a custom list?

Tags: custom-list, forms-services

I am using SharePoint Online which seems to be Microsoft's Software-as-a-Service delivery of SharePoint 2013.

I have created three custom lists, one of which has 20 fields or so. Just to check it out I opened the form in InfoPath and saved it back to the server. I then went to List Settings and from there to Form Settings and selected to delete the InfoPath Form and to revert back to the SharePoint Form.

Unfortunately, now the "new item" link on the list is broken and leads to an HTML 404.

How can I resolve this?

UPDATE:

I opened in InfoPath again and saved back to the server. Then I went back to the Form Settings and set it back to the SharePoint Form, except this time, I did not select the checkbox to delete the InfoPath Form. Now my "new item" link is working again and pointing to the SharePoint Form.

So I will change my question to, why did checking that box break my "new item" link? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have same problem as you have described. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

When you do delete infopath form from Form settings it also deleted its default template. And on other side new item link did not get any direct connection to open this form hence it showed 404. Next time you did restore same form so it got correctd and new item link got form refrence and so it started working again.